# VS Code running wrong py interpreter while running my code but it works fine with python IDLE so idk how to set path of interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio, user-interface, path, pyqt

[This is the image of the code in vs code and it looks fine with no problems being flagged and no importing issue but when ran it shows no libraries such as PyQt5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRHcb.png)

[This is the proof that it worked fine and successfully did an entry when ran with IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxatJ.png)

So issue is like I want to use different python version for like two projects but it's only using the interpreter pathway after i've deleted that version of python from my Laptop...

How to resolve this issue?

[After Deleting the path too it's showing .....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISkHJ.png)

I was expecting that programme would run as i had installed python 3.8 for some pyside project which were working fine but when i switched to python 3.11 for running up my project 11 version of py .. It was still running it from 3.8 version ... so idk how to solve this if you know please do help me out...

Comment: It says that the module was not found meaning the Python environment in vscode doesn’t have the Python qt module installed. Maybe if you try to pip install PyQt5 in the vscode console? It just looks to the like the global environment idle uses and the virtual environment I assume vscode is using don’t both have PyQt5 installed.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 Bro ik when it's installed or not if i'll use pyqt5 install it'll show me all the requirements are met with installed version on py38 version folder